# Regular Expression to match a number followed by that many characters?

Tags: regex

I would like to match strings that follow this pattern: "N: N-character-string"

Valid examples:

```
5. Fives
12. AbcdAbcdAbcd
1. O
0. 
3. Tre
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with a single regex? I'm happy to accept any flavor of regular expression.

Comment: What language are you using? What you are trying to achieve can be easily obtained by splitting the string and then checking that the length of the second part is the same as the value held in the first part.

Comment: I don't think you can do that as there is no memory in regex

Comment: No regex engine I know supports this. Regexes match (and can capture) text, but they don't support parsing it into numerical values.

Comment: Those examples aren’t regular language, so it’s not possible with a regex.

Comment: If you are using Java or C#, just parse each line, split on space, and compare the number against the length of the second string from the split.

Comment: Mmm. I don't actually have a task in mind. I was just suddenly very curious as to whether such a thing could be done using only a regex, having clearly forgotten everything i learned about regular languages.

Comment: Not possible with regex, but surely possible with programming languages or tools like awk

Answer (score 2):

No You can't do this with regex.

Finite automation (underlying data structure used by regex) has no support for memory. That is, on the lexical analysis done by your regex, your input is broken down into tokens and you can not use token from a previous stage to be used for further parsing on later stage.

Read [Theory of automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory) for more theoretical background to this.